# Como implementar "LOCATIONCOMPONENT" en lugar de "MOCK_DEVICE_LOCATION_LAT_LNG" de MapBox en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox

Estoy tratando de mostrar en un RecyclerView los datos de distancia de ubicacion de "puntos" con respecto a la ubicacion del usuario, los datos de los puntos estan en una lista Json.
Suplantar la ubicacion falsa por la ubicacion real del usuario.
    `private static final LatLng MOCK_DEVICE_LOCATION_LAT_LNG = new LatLng(40.713469, -74.006735);`

Añadir el marcador de ubicación del dispositivo falso al mapa. En un caso de uso real, El LocationComponent del SDK de Maps se puede usar para mostrar y personalizar fácilmente la ubicación del dispositivo

```
`addMockDeviceLocationMarkerToMap();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haria en este caso seria utilizar la actualizacion de posicion del usuario para generar el objeto LatLng, dibujarlo en el mapa, de la misma manera generar un ArrayList con los datos del archivo json, a continuación comparar hallar la disancia de cada elemento del Array con el punto de referencia, y generando un array de modelos o POJOS que contengan las posiciones comparadas y su distancia, para al final alimentar con estos POJOs el RecyclerView